# React typscript - component with interface and additional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm totally new to using Typescript and having problems rendering a component but also passing in an onClick function. How can I pass in an onClick function to the CarItem Like this? I think it's trying to treat the onMenuClick as a proeprty of ICar but it isn't and shouldn't be. The onMenuClick shouldn't be part of the ICar interface. It is merely a function. I've put a simple example below.

```
interface ICar {
    name: string,
    colour: string,
    manufacturer: string
}

const CarGrid : React.FC<ICarGridProps> = car => {
    return (
        <CarItem {...car} onMenuClick={onClick} />
    )
}

const CarItem : React.FC<ICar> = (car, onMenuClick) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(car.name)}>{car.name}</div>
    );
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: The CarItem params should receive an object, instead of two params.
I think you meant to use it like:
```
const CarItem : React.FC<{car: ICar, onMenuClick: Function}> = ({car, onMenuClick}) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(car.name)}>{car.name}</div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:
I've corrected the return of `CarGrid` and type def and params of `CarItem`

```
interface ICar {
    name: string,
    colour: string,
    manufacturer: string
}

const CarGrid : React.FC<ICarGridProps> = car => {
    return (
        <CarItem car={car} onMenuClick={onClick} /> 
    )
}

const CarItem : React.FC<{car: ICar, onMenuClick: Function}> = ({car, onMenuClick}) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(car.name)}>{car.name}</div>
    );
}
```

Or if you want to spread the car object into CarItem, it should be refactored:

```
...
<CarItem {...car} onMenuClick={onClick} />
...

const CarItem : React.FC<ICar&{onMenuClick: Function}> = ({name, onMenuClick}) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => onMenuClick(name)}>{name}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sir, you are my hero! Thank you SO much. This was really causing me trouble! I'm trying to refactor some of our code using TS and I'm completely new to it. It all makes perfect sense now. Thank you :)